# Determine minimum number of length 7 bit strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am unsure if my answer is correct for this question.

Determine minimum number of length 7 bit strings required to guarantee that at least 23 strings contain an odd number of 0's

Using the formula n!/(k!*(n!-k!)) I was able to determine that there are 
7 possibilities for 1 zero, 
35 possibilities for 3 zeroes, 
21 possibilities for 5 zeroes, 
and 1 possibility for all 7 being zero.

Would the minimum number just be the smallest number I can make greater than 23?

So in this case it would be 28 length 7 bit strings, by adding 21 and 7?

Comment: It will be total number of strings with even zeros plus 23

Comment: I see, the minimum would be 86. Since there are 63 strings with even zeroes, the same amount as those with odd zeroes. But if the string were to be all 1s, would that be considered a even or odd amount of zeroes? If it counts as even, then the answer would be 87.

Comment: yes, 0 is even also